# ASCII character table Python 3

Tags: python, ascii

I am trying to make this ASCII list with rows of 10 and 1 space apart in each row. I cannot make them separate without messing up the table. I want it to not spit out a long row of characters.

The table is supposed to look like this.

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) *
+ , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = >
? @ A B C D E F G H
I J K L M N O P Q R 
S T U V W X Y Z [ \ 
] ^ _ ` a b c d e f 
g h i j k l m n o p 
q r s t u v w x y z 
{ | } ~
```

Here is my code:

```
for v in range(33,127):
    if v <= 42:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 43 and v <= 52:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 53 and v <= 62:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 63 and v <= 72:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 73 and v <= 82:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 83 and v <= 92:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 93 and v <= 102:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 103  and v <= 112:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 113  and v <= 122:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    elif v >= 123 and v <= 127:
        print(chr(v), end = ' ')
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code :

```
start = 33
end = 127
for v in range(start, end):
    if (start - v) % 10 == 0: # check if (start - v) is a multiple of 10
        print("")
    print(chr(v), end=' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is a pretty flexible language. This will get you most of what you want:

```
print "\n".join(" ".join(map(chr, range(x, x+10))) for x in range(33, 128, 10))
```

This extends past your desired maximum value of 127 on the last row. Fixing that is left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to learn about the `.format` [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) in python3 , so I came up with a one-liner to do the trick.

```
print(5*' '+(16*'{:#4x}').format(*range(16)),
      *['{:#4x}|'.format(i*16) + (16*'{:4c}').format(*range(16*i,16*(i+1))) 
        for i in range(2,8)], sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
      0x0 0x1 0x2 0x3 0x4 0x5 0x6 0x7 0x8 0x9 0xa 0xb 0xc 0xd 0xe 0xf
0x20|       !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /
0x30|   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?
0x40|   @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
0x50|   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _
0x60|   `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
0x70|   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~
```

Not exactly what was ordered, but a little more aesthetic in my opinion.

Explanation: `'{:#4x}'.format(val)` outputs `val` (a supposed `int`) formatted as hexidecimal (`x`) with the `0x` before it (`#`) in a field 4 characters wide (`4`).  `16*'{:4c}'` creates 16 fields, 4 characters wide, which format whatever `int` they get as a `char`, which are provided by the [iterable unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-starred-expression) expression `*range(...)`.